# Detect all Non-Alphabetical Values to Replace with NA

Tags: r, date, replace, symbols, alphabetical

I have columns where instead of NA for missing values, a random symbol is put in its place. I would like to transform all these random symbols into NAs. How can I do that?

Edit: Dates also in columns need to be replaced by NAs

i.e.

```
Canada          Canada
#               NA
South Africa    South Africa
Portugal        Portugal
12/3/2017       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub`. Here we replace anything that is either not (`^`) a letter or number (`[:alnum:]`) or a space with `NA`.

```
target <- c("Canada","#","South Africa","Portugal")
gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]",NA, target)
#[1] "Canada"       NA             "South Africa" "Portugal"
```